# docker compose: create two containers from one image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a docker image and two `docker-compose.yml` files.

I want to create **two containers** for that image, each based on its own docker-compose.yml.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-f` lets you define [multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services) which can be loaded at once. Existing services are overridden / extended, additional services are being added to your composition:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

For example:

```
# docker-compose.base.yml

version: '2'
services:
  firstcontainer:
    image: alpine
```

and another:

```
# docker-compose.prod.yml

version: '2'
services:
  secondcontainer:
    image: alpine
```